# Group By in Groovy

Tags: groovy, collections, grouping

I have a list of object as follows

```
[["GX 470","Model"],["Lexus","Make"],["Jeep","Make"],["Red","Color"],["blue","Color"]]
```

and I want to transform it to

```
{"Model":["GX 470"],"Make":["Lexus","Jeep"],"Color":["Red", "blue"]}
```

I tried

```
list.groupBy{ it[1] }
```

But that returns me

```
{"Model":[["GX 470","Model"]],"Make":[["Lexus","Make"],["Jeep","Make"]],"Color":[["Red","Color"],["blue","Color"]]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take your intermediate result and just transform it one step further:

```
list.groupBy{ it[1] }.collectEntries{ k, v -> [(k):v*.get(0)] }
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because `groupBy` doesn't remove the element it grouped by from the original object, so you get all the original data, just grouped by a key.

You can use `inject` (and `withDefault`) for more custom grouping:

```
list.inject([:].withDefault{[]}) { map, elem ->
    map[elem[1]] << elem[0]
    map
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list.groupBy{ it[1] }.collect { key,value -> value.get(0) }
```